# VBA create graph without cell range reference?

Tags: vba, graph

Is it possible to create a bar graph via VBA without using a reference to a range in the sheet? I have the values in the code already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to feed `Arrays` to the `Series`. i.e.

```
Sub Example()
    With Sheet1.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, 300, 300).Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
      .Name = "Example"
      .XValues = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
      .Values = Array(1, 4, 9, 16, 25)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I get Run-time error '424': Object required. In the 'With...' line.

Comment: I get Run-time error '424': Object required. In the 'With...' line. I do have a sheet named 'Sheet1', so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sub Example()
    With Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, 300, 300).Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
      .Name = "Example"
      .XValues = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
      .Values = Array(1, 4, 9, 16, 25)
    End With
End Sub